# Pushing PHP function value to another file

Tags: php, css, menu, header

I've got a file `Page.php`

```
<?php
$title = "1";                  
$menu[0] = "1";   
$menu[1] = "2";

function mainNav($menu) {
    foreach ($menu as $value){ 
        if ($title == $value){   
            $active = "active";
        } 
        else {
            $active = " ";
        }
        echo $active ;
        return $active;
    }
}

include "header.php";
```

And a file `header.php`

```
<li class="mainNav <?php mainNav(); ?>" style="z-index:8">
<a href="http://www.com"><?php echo $menu[7]; ?></a></li>
```

I would like `header.php` to contain `li class="mainNav active"` if `$title == $menu[x]`. Otherwise `li class="mainNav"`. Having some difficulty and can't figure it out.

Comment: You don't pass $menu, also that function returns on the first item in the theoretical argument $menu. Would probably be best to have the `li`s themselves being entirely generated by PHP, then output that.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new to PHP. I thought I did pass $menu with 
function mainNav($menu) {

Comment: And you mean generate the li with something like this:
<?php
echo '<li class="mainNav' . $active .'" style="z-index:8"><a href="/2.php'"><a href="http://www.com">' . $menu[2] . '</a></li>'

Comment: Kinda though I'm more fond of the `<?php [loop stuff]{ ?> raw html <?php echo("dynamic"); ?> raw html <?php }` structure for this kind of thing. Less backslash\\plague.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are trying to call function `mainNav()` without any arguments. But you declared function with argument `$menu`. So, php can't find function `mainNav()` without any arguments.
2. In function `mainNav($menu)` you are trying to access variable `$title`, that haven't been defined in this function. So, if you want to access veriable `$title` you should use `$this->title`
3. Your function returns value after the first iteration of the loop. I think, it is wrong. Use function [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) instead of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you just wants to add class as "active" for menu then you can go with this code:

```
function mainNav($title) {
    $menu = array("Menu1","Menu2","Menu3");
    $html = '';
    foreach ($menu as $value){ 
        if ($title == $value){   
            $html .= '<li class="mainNav active" style="z-index:8">'.$value.'</li>';
        } else {
            $html .= '<li class="mainNav" style="z-index:8">'.$value.'</li>';
        }
    } 
    return $html;
}
```

Pass active menu in function like this in header.php

```
<ul><?php echo mainNav('Menu1'); ?></ul>
```

Comment: That's not how `foreach` works.... you're `return`ing unconditionally before `foreach` gets to loop.

Comment: Sorry! my bad. Corrected now.

Comment: Well, now the problem is semantic- it's gonna return "active" whenever `$title` is contained in `$menu` (which in the example snippets is always). I'll remove the downvote since you also fixed the scoping problem ^_^